# How can I extract the text outside the <em> tag in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

Can someone help me extract the test that is after the *From*, I want to extract the sender name. It is situated right outside the em tag. I'm using the python BeautifulSoup package.

Here is a link to the webpage: http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2016/Jan/0

I was able to extract the email title successfully since is was in a  tag. There are no other div's or classes in the html page.

This is the html code of the page:

Here is what I've tried

```
def title_spider(max_pages):
    page = 0
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2016/Jan/' + str(page)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for email_title in soup.find('b'):
            title = email_title.string
            print(title)

        for date_stamp in soup.em:
            date = date_stamp
            print(date)
        page += 1

title_spider(2)
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the next sibling and if you want the specific em's From and Date you can combine with a regex:

```
import re

def title_spider(max_pages):
    for page in range(max_pages + 1):
        url = 'http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2016/Jan/{}'.format(page) 
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for email_title in soup.find('b'):
            title = email_title.string
            print(title)

        for em in soup.find_all("em", text=re.compile("From|Date")):
            print(em.text, em.next_sibling)
```

Which gives you:

```
In [5]: title_spider(2)
Alcatel Lucent Home Device Manager - Management Console Multiple XSS
From : Uğur Cihan KOÇ <u.cihan.koc () gmail com>
Date : Sun, 3 Jan 2016 13:20:53 +0200
Executable installers/self-extractors are vulnerable^WEVIL  (case 17): Kaspersky Labs utilities
From : "Stefan Kanthak" <stefan.kanthak () nexgo de>
Date : Sun, 3 Jan 2016 16:12:50 +0100
Possible vulnerability in F5 BIG-IP LTM - Improper input validation of the HTTP version number of the HTTP reqest allows any payload size and conent to pass through
From : Eitan Caspi <eitanc () yahoo com>
Date : Sun, 3 Jan 2016 21:10:27 +0000 (UTC)
```

Comment: Could you send me the entire code that was used to implement this ?

Comment: @KarthikJ, replace `for date_stamp in soup.em:` with the logic above

Comment: @Padriac, I am getting a utf-8 encoding error. I was able to fix it by changing my print(x)  statement to print(x.encode("utf-8"). Is there any better way to convert the encoding ?

Comment: @KarthikJ, are you using python2 or 3?

Comment: @Padriac, I'm using python 3

Comment: line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u011f' in position 3: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Your default encoding is cp1252, the issue is with cmd more than python. You could try to set your code page to something that supports utf-8 or stick to encoding manually. I don't use windows but I know cmd is not the best when it comes to handling utf-8, I would recommend installing cygwin or using an ide like pycharm which has a free community edition